# how to show only my query result in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

i am trying to get the result of my query into datagridview i managed to make add,update and delete but i have a little trouble in "find" query, i used querybuilder and wrote the query and execute it as well but with the same code that showing tables data in gridview i get nothing at all,i want the datagridview only show searched result
i use sql express 2008

thanks in advance :)

this is my update query:

```
ownersTBLTableAdapter1.UpdateQuery(name_txtbox.Text,phone_txtbox.Text);
this.ownersTBLTableAdapter1.Fill(this.rtmS_DS1.OwnersTBL);
```

and this is a the useless code:

```
 private void search_tlstb_txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ownersTBLTableAdapter1.FindQuery(search_tlstb_txtbox.Text);
           this.ownersTBLTableAdapter1.Fill(this.rtmS_DS1.OwnersTBL);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it worked

```
 private void search_tlstb_txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search_tlstb_txtbox.Text != string.Empty && owners_dgv.RowCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < owners_dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < owners_dgv.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (owners_dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(search_tlstb_txtbox.Text))
                    {
                        owners_dgv.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        owners_dgv.CurrentCell = null;
                        owners_dgv.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
            this.OwnersTBLTableAdapter1.Fill(this.rtmS_DS1.OwnersTBL);
    }
```

Comment: This wont work well with large amounts of data as you are literally looping through every cell

Comment: i put a break command for that and maybe you right but my tables data are not too many even after years. anyway if you have a better idea let me know

Answer (score 1):

First off I assume you are using a DataSet

So you could use something like

```
ownersTBLTableAdapter1.Fill(rtmS_DS1.OwnersTBL);
dataGridView1.DataSource = rtmS_DS1.OwnersTBL;
```

In your text changed event then you could apply a filter to the defaultview

so if the DataSet type is DS1 then it would be

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DS1.OwnersTBL).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", search_tlstb_txtbox.Text);
```

and "Field" should be replaced with your column name

after reading again replacing the 
    string.Format("Field = '{0}'", search_tlstb_txtbox.Text)

with
    string.Format("Field LIKE '%{0}%'", search_tlstb_txtbox.Text)

Will probably get you what your after though

Any questions let me know

Comment: thank you JohnyHarkness i am new in sql ,could you explain what should i put instead DS1, i tried so much :|

Comment: Can you add more of your code to the question so i can see what your doing?

Comment: What did you name your dataset when you created it?

Comment: i have these objects :ownersTBLBindingSource ,tableAdapterManager1 ,ownersTBLTableAdapter1 ,rtmS_DS1 and dataset name is "RTMS_DS". i added a sql databank name RTMS_DB with OwnersTBL and the above dataset rest of the works was auto with query builder.

Comment: Then instead of DS1 use RTMS_DS, also make sure that you set the datasource of the grid in the way i have detailed otherwise it wont work.

Comment: To be honest your approach sounds quite complicated for what you are trying to do. If you post up more of your code i could explain what to do much better

Comment: i get this error 'RTMS_Pro.RTMS_DS.OwnersTBL' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' , i just want as user typing in the search box the similar result are going to be selected and the rest of rows go invisible. sorry for bother you i will manage it at least some how, Best regards

Comment: What is RTMS_Pro? Honestly though put up your code and i will have a look

Comment: finally i find out how. the rules says after 8 hours i can post the answer but anyway thanks again and the RTMS_Pro is rad truck managment system